# How can I compile a LWC to use it as a standard web component via customElements.define()?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

I'm trying to compile a LWC to a standard web component, so that after importing it I could just use it as any standard HTML tag:

```
<html>
    <script type="module" src="./modules/myWebComponent.js"></script>
    <body>
        <my-web-component>VS Code</my-web-component>
    </body>
</html>
```

Compiled class would be something like this:

```
class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        
        // Whatever my WC needs to do
    }
}

customElements.define("my-web-component", MyWebComponent);
```

Basically I need the HTMLElement built from my LWC. I've seen there is a `CustomElementConstructor` as described [here](https://lwc.dev/guide/install#use-lightning-web-components-as-native-web-components), but I'm not able to compile it so that the generated .js file has the lwc import resolved, or the CustomElementConstructor exported.

I've also tried to use Rollup as explained [here](https://lwc.dev/guide/install#via-rollup) but I don't want to use `createElement` exported from LWC, I just want the compiled file to contain an HTMLElement I could use via `customElements.define()` and let the browser natively resolve the web component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the setup to create the Rollup or Webpack configuration, including src/modules, src/main.js, lwc.config.json, package.json, and rollup.config.js or webpack.config.js.

Once you're all set up, notice how src/main.js reads:

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import App from 'x/app';

const elm = createElement('x-app', { is: App });
document.body.appendChild(elm);
```

All you have to do is replace that with:

```
import App from 'x/app';
customElements.define('x-app', App.CustomElementConstructor);
```

And then you can reference that script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-app></x-app>
    <script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Make sure you define every component that you intend to use so they're all properly registered with the browser. You don't even have to call `document.createElement`; just having it in the HTML will render it. You can also choose to use `document.createElement` and thing slike `Element.appendChild`.

I found this by scanning the LWC source, where I found this tidbit:

```
/**
 * This static getter builds a Web Component class from a LWC constructor so it can be registered
 * as a new element via customElements.define() at any given time. E.g.:
 *
 *      import Foo from 'ns/foo';
 *      customElements.define('x-foo', Foo.CustomElementConstructor);
 *      const elm = document.createElement('x-foo');
 *
 */
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was close, I think I was missing the correct setup for module resolution in lwc.config.json, so import wasn't working correctly and CustomElementConstructor was undefined. Working now !